# Cross-compiling vs virtualization

Tags: virtual-machine, cross-compiling

I want my app to run in Windows and Ubuntu, in both 32- and 64-bit modes. So I must compile four times and also test it four times. The question is whether it's best to use cross-compiling or compile in virtual-machine (VM) like VirtualBox.

I know cross-compiling is hard for the first time, but this way I can keep the VM for testing "clean", with no development stuff that may hide some lack of files in the final user PC. On the other hand, compiling directly in a VM is quite more simple.

So I ask:

- What are other pros/cons for each method?
- Which is the *right* way?
- Which is the most used way and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:** In this case, skip cross-compilation. Build and test on each target platform directly.

**Details:** If you need to ship your software on these 4 platforms, you will need either physical or virtual manifestations of them, regardless of whether you cross-compile or compile natively on the target platform.

Why? Because you will want to run tests on **every** target platform, not just one.

Why? Because your cross-compiler could have bugs on one platform but not another, and because 32-bit vs. 64-bit as well as Linux vs. Windows are sufficiently different. For example, if you only run tests on Ubuntu-32, but cross-compile to Windows-64 and ship the software, you might find a problem only once it reaches the customer.

Cross-compiling is hard to set up and hard to maintain. Given that you're going to want to test the code, the installation, etc. on every of these platforms, you might as well skip the cross-compilation and just run builds and tests on each of the target platforms directly.

Speaking of keeping VM state "clean": don't set it up manually, create it from scratch every time. Use tools like [Packer](http://www.packer.io/) and [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) to automate the builds, and use clean VMs every time to ensure it's reproducible and hermetic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I going to use two VM for each target, one to do development and the "clean" one for testing.